# Oracle SQL query previous row result

Tags: sql, oracle

I am just stuck now, now getting the logic to solve this query. Find the below tables and the output. There is Table A and table B which matches two column ID and DATE. If Date got matched then it should multiply the qty with percent else it should pick previous percent.

```
Table A                 Table B     
ID  Date    Percent     ID  Date    Qty
A   01/01/17    0.5     A   01/01/17    10
A   04/01/17    1       A   02/01/17    20
A   06/01/17    2       A   03/01/17    30
B   02/01/17    5       A   05/01/17    40
B   05/01/17    10      A   06/01/17    50
                        A   07/01/17    60
                        A   08/01/17    40
                        B   01/01/17    10
                        B   02/01/17    50

============================================

column  column  column  comment comment comment
  ID    Date       Qty          Previous percent if row not matched 
   A    01/01/17   0.5 * 10         0.5 got new percent
   A    02/01/17   0.5 * 20         0.5 
   A    03/01/17   0.5 * 30         0.5 
   A    04/01/17   1*  0              1 got new percent but no qty found 
   A    05/01/17   1 * 40             1 
   A    06/01/17   2 * 50             2 got new percent
   B    01/01/17   10 * 0             0 no percent found
   B    02/02/17   5 * 10             5 got new percent
   B    5/1/17     10 * 0            10 got new percent
```

Comment: The "output" table (??) shows a row for the date 04/01/17, which is not present in either of the input tables. WHY? Is that part of the requirement? If it is, please update the post to make that explicit.

Comment: @mathguy: 04/01/17 is in the second row of Table A.  ???

Comment: @BobJarvis - Ugh. I really meant in Table B. More generally - is there a requirement that all months be present in the final result? But then I looked at the rest of the output and it doesn't make any sense. What's with 5/5/17, for example?  (last row in the output) I decided to ignore the "output" and interpret the problem "my way".

Comment: @yAshu: in the last "results" row, should the date be "05/01/17" instead of "5/5/17"?

Comment: It is 05/01/17. Typo mistake

Answer (score 0):

I interpreted the problem to mean "add a few more columns to Table B" - to show the "most current" percentage, showing its date from Table A, and the "gross quantity" from Table B and the "net quantity" by multiplying by the proper percentage.

If you also need one row for every row in Table A, simply delete the `WHERE` clause from the outermost query (towards the bottom of the query).

```
with table_a ( id, dt, pct ) as (
       select 'A', to_date('01/01/17', 'mm/dd/rr'),  0.5 from dual union all
       select 'A', to_date('04/01/17', 'mm/dd/rr'),  1   from dual union all
       select 'A', to_date('06/01/17', 'mm/dd/rr'),  2   from dual union all
       select 'B', to_date('02/01/17', 'mm/dd/rr'),  5   from dual union all
       select 'B', to_date('05/01/17', 'mm/dd/rr'), 10   from dual
  ), table_b ( id, dt, qty ) as (
       select 'A', to_date('01/01/17', 'mm/dd/rr'), 10   from dual union all
       select 'A', to_date('02/01/17', 'mm/dd/rr'), 20   from dual union all
       select 'A', to_date('03/01/17', 'mm/dd/rr'), 30   from dual union all
       select 'A', to_date('05/01/17', 'mm/dd/rr'), 40   from dual union all
       select 'A', to_date('06/01/17', 'mm/dd/rr'), 50   from dual union all
       select 'A', to_date('07/01/17', 'mm/dd/rr'), 60   from dual union all
       select 'A', to_date('08/01/17', 'mm/dd/rr'), 40   from dual union all
       select 'B', to_date('01/01/17', 'mm/dd/rr'), 10   from dual union all
       select 'B', to_date('02/01/17', 'mm/dd/rr'), 50   from dual
  )
-- end of test data (not part of the SQL query); query begins BELOW THIS LINE
select   id, qty_date, pct_date, qty as gross_qty, pct, qty * pct as net_qty
from     ( select id, dt as qty_date,
                  last_value(case flag when 0 then dt end ignore nulls)
                                    over (partition by id order by dt) as pct_date,
                  last_value(pct ignore nulls) 
                                    over (partition by id order by dt, flag) as pct,
                  qty, flag
           from   ( select    id, dt, pct, null as qty, 0 as flag
                      from    table_a
                    union all
                    select    id, dt, null as pct, qty, 1 as flag
                      from    table_b
                  )
         )
where    flag = 1       
order by id, qty_date       --  if needed
;
```

**Output**:

```
ID QTY_DATE   PCT_DATE    GROSS_QTY        PCT    NET_QTY
-- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
A  2017-01-01 2017-01-01         10         .5          5
A  2017-02-01 2017-01-01         20         .5         10
A  2017-03-01 2017-01-01         30         .5         15
A  2017-05-01 2017-04-01         40          1         40
A  2017-06-01 2017-06-01         50          2        100
A  2017-07-01 2017-06-01         60          2        120
A  2017-08-01 2017-06-01         40          2         80
B  2017-01-01                    10
B  2017-02-01 2017-02-01         50          5        250

9 rows selected.
```

Comment: A  2017-05-01 2017-04-01         40          1         40 << this row is wrong it should display the correct month ...                                                               A  2017-04-01 2017-04-01        Null         1         0               add another row                                                            A  2017-05-01 2017-05-01         40          1         40

Comment: @yAshu - Why is `null` times (anything) equal to zero, and not to `null`? Other than that, I already said in my Answer: "If you also need one row for every row in Table A, simply delete the `WHERE` clause from the outermost query (towards the bottom of the query)." Can you find it? It is the second paragraph in my Answer! Now: if you need to show zero instead of `NULL` for `net_qty`, select `coalesce(qty, 0) * pct as net_qty` instead of simply `qty * pct` in the `SELECT` of the outer query. I assume if you don't have `pct` (first row for B) then `net_qty` should still be `null`, right?

Comment: I used the same logic in my query using analytical function LAST VALUE....I came here to know if there could be a another alternative solution of this query... but you wrote the approximately same solution...Well thank you @mathguy. Kudos !!

Comment: @yAshu - there are other ways to solve this problem, in particular using joins. However, in almost all cases if you can use `union all` and analytic functions and avoid joins, the query will run much faster. My understanding is that analytic functions were introduced *exactly* for this reason - to significantly reduce the need for time-consuming joins.